# My problem with getting the current month as default in django

Tags: python, django

I have 2 models. AyModel == MonthModel and OdemelerModel == PaymentModel

first model is:

```
class AyModel(models.Model):
    AYLAR = (
        ("Ocak", "Ocak"),
        ("Şubat", "Şubat"),
        ("Mart", "Mart"),
        ("Nisan", "Nisan"),
        ("Mayıs","Mayıs"),
        ("Haziran","Haziran"),
        ("Temmuz","Temmuz"),
        ("Ağustos", "Ağustos"),
        ("Eylül", "Eylül"),
        ("Ekim", "Ekim"),
        ("Kasım", "Kasım"),
        ("Aralık","Aralık"),
    )

    ay = models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=AYLAR)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ay

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Ay'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Aylar'
```

and second model is:

```
class OdemelerModel(models.Model):
    odeme_ay = models.ForeignKey(AyModel,default=datetime.now().strftime('%B'), on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

Whatever record I enter into the database first for AyModel, that record appears by default in OdemelerModel. How Can I Solve This?
Thanks..

I want this month to have odeme_ay by default. The same problem occurs in my other model called YearModel.

Comment: It is not clear to me what the problem is.

Comment: `ForeignKey` should be the instance of the related model. You can't add a DateTime instance in it. Also, it's difficult to understand what your problem exactly is.

Comment: Did you provided the AyModel object while saving data to OdemelerModel?
month_obj = AyModel.objects.get(ay=...)
OdemelerModel(odeme_ay=month_obj)